# Is there a way to import a variable in python without looping code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, command-line, os.system

I have looked at multiple different questions and answers but nothing I have looked at is helping me in the slightest. I am using Python 3 for all of this.

I am having a bit of trouble using python to transfer a variable to be used in a command-line prompt through python code. I am using os.system, and would prefer to use this, to execute a second python file, in the same folder.
The opening through command prompt works after a bit of testing, but when I try to import a variable from the first python code, it loops through the entire first bit of code.

My first python code is as follows:

```
import os
variable_to_transfer=input()
os.system('cmd /c "python file2.py"')
```

My second python code is as follows:

```
import os
from file1.py import variable_to_transfer
command='cmd /k "ping {0}"'.format(variable_to_transfer)
os.system(command)
```

When I run this set of code it runs through the first code once, goes to the second code and doesn't do anything at the line

```
from file1.py import variable_to_transfer
```

I intend for my codes to transfer the variable but it just loops. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Why use a subprocess here at all? Why not just `import`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It loops because your `file1` is calling your `file2` which imports from your `file1` and recall your `file2`, etc. over and over. What you should do instead, is pass the variable as an argument and retrieve it from there. For example:

```py
# file1.py

import os
variable_to_transfer=input()
os.system('cmd /c "python file2.py %s"' % variable_to_transfer)
```

```py
# file2.py

import os
import sys
command='cmd /k "ping {0}"'.format(sys.argv[1])
os.system(command)
```

Comment: Why use a subprocess at all, why not just have an import?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is something you will have to ask Michael Pate about. I answered based on what was provided in the question and him specifically wanting to `use os.system to execute a second python file`.